# Sample /etc/apt/sources.list for Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management

It seems my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file only has

> deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17 *Qiana* - Release amd64 20140624]/ trusty contrib main non-free

It might have got corrupted when I was trying to download `pdfedit`. When I try to download some software now it says:

> This is a major failure of your software management system. Please check for broken packages with synaptic, check the file permissions and correctness of the file '/etc/apt/sources.list' and reload the software information with: 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install -f'.

Comment: Try: [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=168251) post on the Linux Mint Forums

Comment: @garethTheRed the post has the list for 32 bit and I need for 64 bit.  Also, I need for Linux Mint 17 and not Ubuntu.  Are they the same?  Here is my machine details: `Linux indranil-thinkPad-s431 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: No, those sources are for mint. The default sources file includes the Ubuntu sources _and_  packages.linuxmint.com. As for 64 vs 32, that's irrelevant for the sources, you use the same and your system chooses the right one.

Answer (score 4):

From my own system, a Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` contains this:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca main upstream import 
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is empty.